# Best practice to check and add missing stores in Dexie.js

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, dexie

I'm just switching to Dexie.js for dealing with IndexedDB in our web application. I like it, but I wonder what would be the best way to check (and add automatically) for any missing tables on startup? The native way would be using *.onupgradeneeded*, is there something similar in Dexie?

Suppose I have something like this in my initialization:

```
    self.idb = new Dexie("myApp");
    self.idb.version(1).stores({
        languages: 'id',
        stationDatapoints: 'id, stationId, datapointId',
        dpTranslations: 'id, l, r',
        datapoints: 'id',
        stations: 'id',
    });
    self.idb.open().catch(function (e) {
        console.error("Open failed: " + e);
    });
```

With this, as soon as I delete one of the tables and reload the application, I get an error when accessing the respective table for querying. However, when I delete the whole database and reload the application, all tables are created automatically. How can I automatically create single missing tables? Or do I have to check and add them manually?

Answer (score 0):

It's covered here: [Database Versioning](https://dexie.org/docs/Tutorial/Design#database-versioning)

Basically, you leave your version(1) declaration intact and add a version(2) with the changes you apply. Keep old versions as long as there are devices out there having it installed. When you are certain all client devices are upgraded, you can remove the earlier declarations.